# Is there anyone who understand the proof of Campbell theorem in the book 'Poisson Processes' written by Kingman?

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory

The proof is in page 28 of the book 'Poisson Processes' written by Kingman. There are some gap related to complex analysis. I want to know the gap, such as 'analyticity of some functions' and 'analytic continuation'.

$E(e^{-uS})=\exp{\int{(e^{-uf(x)}-1)}m(dx)}$ for nonnegative measurable function $f$, non-negative real number $u$
where $m$ is a measure which is finite on compact sets on $R^n$ and $S$ is a nonnegative random variable.

From this Fact, The book says "Then  both sides of $E(e^{zS})=\exp{\int{(e^{zf(x)}-1)}m(dx)}$ equation are analytic functions of z in $Re(z)\le0$, so that $E(e^{-uS})=\exp{\int{(e^{-uf(x)}-1)}m(dx)}$ holds for $Re(z)\le0$."

My first Question is Why $E(e^{zS})$ and $\exp{\int{(e^{zf(x)}-1)}m(dx)}$ are analytic functions of z in $Re(z)\le0$ ?

$E(e^{zS})=\exp{\int{(e^{zf(x)}-1)}m(dx)}$ for measurable function $f$, pure imaginary $z$ where S is a random variable.

From this Fact, The book says "Thus $E(e^{zS})=\exp{\int{(e^{zf(x)}-1)}m(dx)}$ holds at least for imaginary $z$ and its extension to all complex $z$ for which the integral converges is a matter of analytic continuation."

Why?? I want to know more detail.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. It would be useful if you provided a clear question with all the relevant information rather than directing users to a book which may or may not be accessible to them. Also, be clear about where you are stuck.

Comment: The answer is: Yes.

Comment: To Did. Can you teach me analyticity of the function defined by integral and last part of the proof related to analytic continuation ?

Comment: I understand this proof finally by myself

Comment: Kingmsn understood